How to have Makefile generated by CMake check if an environment variable is set
I'm using CMake to generate Makefiles under Linux.
I'd like the Makefile to check if an environment variable is set (sort of How to ensure Makefile variable is set as a prerequisite?): I'd like make to generate an error if a mandatory env var is not set (else it fails to compile and it's hard for the developper to understand why). Obviously, I cannot  modify the Makefile by hand to do that, but I'd like this code to be added to the Makefile by CMake.
Is that doable?

I don't think that CMake does such things: they are greatly generator-specific (in your case - Make-specific). You may check the variable in the CMakeLists.txt itself, so it will fail even on configuration stage when the variable is not set. If the variable needed for a compile process, then you could create some wrapper around the compiler and pass that wrapper to CMake. That wrapper could check existence of the variable and gracefully fail in case the variable is absent.

Same logic except using a CMake script. So the solution is cross-platform.
Created check_env.cmake:
if(NOT DEFINED ENV{VAR_REQUIRED})
        message(FATAL_ERROR "VAR_REQUIRED not found!")
endif()

Create a custom target so the check is done at build time:
add_custom_target(check_env ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P check_env.cmake
)


Nice approach! Thank you.

Could finally do this using a custom_target:
Created check_env.cmd:
echo OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Check if environment is setup correctly

if defined ENV_VAR_REQUIRED (
    echo ENV_VAR_REQUIRED is defined
) else (
    echo Missing ENV_VAR_REQUIRED 
    exit /b 1
)

Call it upon compilation using a custom target:
add_custom_target(check_env ALL COMMAND check_env.cmd )


This does mean your solution is not cross platform. You could achieve the same logic except have CMake run a CMake script instead. I've made an answer to your question showing this logic.
